# Why express run wrong route whenever page is redirected/restarted?

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 get routes setup whenever "/" and "/:id".  The "/:id" route redirects me back to the "/" route, but at the same time it runs the "/:id"
route again.
As result, I get two console.log() entries whenever I click a button to try "/:id".

```
//app.js
//declaration of variables
var statLight = "ON"

app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.get("/",function(req,res){res.render("home",{statLight:statLight});
});

app.get("/:id",function(req,res){
    if(req.params.id=="ON"){
        statLight="OFF";
        console.log("OFF");
    }else{
        statLight="ON";
        console.log("On");
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

home.ejs (button)

```
LIGHT <button id="light"><a href="/<%=statLight%>"><strong><%=statLight%></strong></button></a>
```

Comment: You need to check the url. Try adding `console.log(req.url)` or use a debugger. This might be a browser trying to fetch a favicon. :) `/favicon.ico` matches `/:id` route.